# HTML5UP, Image is small when browser isnt maximized

Tags: html, css, image

So the title says it, ill upload screenshots of the issue:
Here are the images.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEjBB.png]

[image]

I have tried to fix this but im not the most experienced coder out there. If any one has run into this problem or knows the solution please answer :) Its proboly something simple that i cant find because im stupid, LOL. Any way thank you for looking :)
This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Aerial by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @n33co
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Oracle RPG</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-wide.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-noscript.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="loading">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="bg"></div>
            <div id="overlay"></div>
            <div id="main">

                <!-- Header -->
                    <header id="header">
                        <h1>Oracle RPG</h1>
                        <p>A BETTER EXPERIENCE&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; BUILT FOR THE GAMER &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; BY THE GAMER</p>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-comment"><span class="label">Forums</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-usd"><span class="label">Donor Area</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-youtube-play"><span class="label">Youtube Channel</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-tag"><span class="label">Ranks & Apply Area</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </header>

                <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer">
                        <span class="copyright"><font size="1">&copy; Untitled. Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</span></font>
                    </footer>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your all your css files you state your div with id #bg as follows:

```
bg {
        background-size: 2250px auto; /*the first value is different in all css files*/
        width: 6750px;
    }
```

The first value is the width of you images and the second one the height. The width is different in each of the css files (wide, normal, mobile, etc) so what you have to do is just change the width of the background-size to whatever you want and your problem is gone! :)

Comment: Would you like the whole folder? I have the link for dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3x7d8abzvtnqw1/Aerial.zip?dl=0

Comment: I went into all the CSS files and changed it so all of them say width: 6750px; but it still is having the same problem, even changed the style-mobile

Comment: No no you don't have to change width: 6750px! Only change the first value of the background-size element. So in my example you have to change 2250px to a much smaller value like 750px because like you say, it's way to big in fullscreen!